# How to submit form via ajax using rails bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, error-handling

I followed the tutorial [here](http://ericlondon.com/2014/03/13/rails-4-submit-modal-form-via-ajax-and-render-js-response-as-table-row.html) to add ajax form to my rails app.
Everything works except I don't get error messages on invalid form. When I inspect google chrome console I get

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :   
   at processResponse (rails-ujs.self-661556f….js?body=1:246)
   at rails-ujs.self-661556f….js?body=1:173
   at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (rails-ujs.self-661556f….js?body=1:230)

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 422 (Unprocessable Entity)

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
   at processResponse (rails-ujs.self-661556f….js?body=1:246)
   at rails-ujs.self-661556f….js?body=1:173
   at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (rails-ujs.self-661556f….js?body=1:230) 

POST http://localhost:3000/people 422 (Unprocessable Entity)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is related to unexpected response format from the server because you render json with format.js

I suggest that you move your script that handle errors to a file called `app/views/people/create_errors.js.erb` and add the following line to it, instead of binding ajaxError event in `app/assets/javascripts/people.js`

```
$('form#new_person').render_form_errors(<%= @person.errors.to_json.html_safe %>);
```

In `app/controllers/people_controller.rb` change `create` method to:

```
def create
@person = Person.new(person_params)

respond_to do |format|
  if @person.save
    format.html { redirect_to @person, notice: 'Person was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @person }
    # added:
    format.js   { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @person }
  else
    format.html { render action: 'new' }
    format.json { render json: @person.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    # added:
    format.js   { render 'create_errors', status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

I hope this solve your issue.

Comment: I tried removing the js file and still the same error. It's as if it's not been loaded.

Comment: The error message indicates that the issue is related to processResponse when the server reply to ajax request. could you please print the console.log output ??

Comment: It's doesn't print anything to the console log. It's like it stops at the error and code in the file gets skipped.

Comment: how you send errors in the server side ? `render json: @person.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity` exactly like this or you make changes ??

Comment: `format.html { render :new }`
`format.json { render json: @person.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }`
`format.js { render json: @person.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }`

Comment: I am using rails 5, could it have anything to do with this new UJS?

Comment: I found a [tutorial](https://inopinatus.org/2017/05/05/undocumented-ujs-changes-when-upgrading-to-rails-5.1/) on the changes to the UJS, but still unable to put it together.

Comment: I think it is related to unexpected response from the server . Try to add `"data-type" => :json` to html hash in the people form as a quick solution. but the default is calling url as javascript so you can move your JS logic into people/create.js.erb and render it instead of rendering json with format.js

Comment: I think that will do. Can you add an example in the answer so we can close this question.